# Does SchemaCrawler have the ability to extend to support multiple versions of the same Data Source?

Tags: schema, database-schema, schemacrawler

I am new to SchemaCrawler and impressed with the SchemaCrawler. In my project, I need to retrieve the schema for a different version of the same data source.

Example: How to connect MS SQL server version 2005 and 2019 both at the same time?

Comment: also are you invoking SchemaCrawler in the first place ? code or CLI ?

Comment: You do know that support for 2005 ended 5 years ago already?

Comment: @JamesZ, it was just an example.

Comment: @Ostap, Java API

Comment: Well you shouldn't use examples that aren't what you will actually use because someone might think it's a requirement.

Comment: @JamesZ, thanks in advance? do you know the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either invoking SchemaCrawler twice with different `-url` parameter or handle this in you code.

For the code, look here : https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/schemacrawler-examplecode/src/main/java/com/example/ApiExample.java#L68

Comment: Thanks, Ostap, That I can do but I wanted to know if there is any API'S which are specific to database versions?

Comment: oh I see :) Well at that point it really boils down to what JDBC driver you have on the classpath : https://www.schemacrawler.com/database-support.html ; Also, please run a check on the specific Driver for MS SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix